# Windows 10 CalculatorPackage could not be registered

Tags: windows-10

I am trying this fix:

> Add-AppxPackage -register "C:\Program
>   Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.1601.49020.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\appxmanifest.xml"
>   -DisableDevelopmentMode

But I get this error

> Add-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CF6, Package
>   could not be registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073CF6) NOTE:
>   For additional information, look for [ActivityId]
>   e90d0759-d78a-0003-b82e-42e98ad7d101 in the Event Log or use the
>   command line Get-AppxLog -ActivityID
>   e90d0759-d78a-0003-b82e-42e98ad7d101 At line:1 char:1
>   + Add-AppxPackage -register "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.Win ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Program File...ppxmanifest.xml:String) [Add-AppxPackage], IOException
>       + F

ullyQualifiedErrorId : DeploymentError,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AddAppxPackageCommand

It looks like windows 10 default apps is quickly becoming a huge mess and that Microsoft never provided a tool to fix it easily. Is there any other options other than refreshing my install ?

Issue seems to be occuring after each cumulative update.

Comment: Doesn't happen to me, so what command have you ran, to uninstall these applications in the past?

Comment: I did not ran any specific command. It stopped working after a windows update.

Answer (score 0):

See if this command-line helps..automatically registers the latest version.

```
Get-AppxPackage -allusers Microsoft.WindowsCalculator | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```

Note that the folder name for the current version (10586.420) would be:

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.1605.1582.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
```

Comment: I did this and have the same error. The store doesn't work as well. Same error when trying to register it. I have the same build version.

Comment: I ran DISM but this did not help